# Parse error PHP

Tags: php

My IDE is showing "parse error" on this line of my php file:

> var $meat = new Category(Meat-Free Meat, 1);

I'm trying to make this line of code work:

```
return parent::displayData($viewData);
```

And `$ViewData` needs to be an array of `Category` objects.

Where is my syntax tripping me up?

Here is the full file:

```
class CategorySelect extends BaseSelect {
        static $template = 'select_multiple_template.php';

        public static function display() {
            var $meat = new Category(Meat-Free Meat, 1);
            var $dairy = new Category(Dairy-Free dairy, 2);
            var $confectionery = new Category(Confectionery, 3);
            var $baking = new Category(Baking, 4);
            var $dessert = new Category(Dessert, 5);
            var $viewData = array($meat, $dairy, $confectionery, $baking, $dessert);
            return parent::displayData($viewData);
        }
    }

    class Category {
        function Category($name, $id) {
            $this->name = $name;
            $this->id = $id;
        }
    }
```

Here is the abstract class it is extending:

```
interface iSelect {
    public static function display();
}

abstract class BaseSelect implements iSelect {
    static $template = 'select_template.php';
    public static function displayData($viewData) {
        if ( class_exists( 'View' ) ) {
            $templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . static::$template;
            return View::render( $templatePath, $viewData );
        }
        else {
            return "You are trying to render a template, but we can't find the View Class";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If those items aren't constants they need to be quoted.

Comment: @JayBlanchard you beat me to it, nonetheless would a constant with spaces work (see `Meat-Free Meat`)? I doubt it...

Comment: Likely not @webeno, but the error thrown is likely because PHP tried to interpret a constant that didn't exist.

Comment: agreed, @JayBlanchard

Comment: It's tofu @Don'tPanic :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
var $meat = new Category(Meat-Free Meat, 1);
var $dairy = new Category(Dairy-Free dairy, 2);
```

Meat-Free Meat is as string right? you have to add quotes, then its should be:

```
$meat = new Category("Meat-Free Meat", 1);
$dairy = new Category("Dairy-Free dairy", 2);
```

Comment: Also, you can't use `var` inside a function